# MongoDB: Counting duplicate fields, mapReduce vs python loops

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo

I have a collection where I want to find all the duplicates of a given field. From Mongo documentation and other answers here, most people seem to suggest mapReduce. I was wondering what are the disadvantages of just iterating through a cursor from python instead of using map reduce.

It seem like mapreduce too have to iterate through the objects anyway.

Adding the solution here, so that might help someone.

I ran the following query to get a list of all the barcodes that are present more than once. `$group` pipe counts the number of occurrences, and `$match` filters the ones with `count` of more than `1`.

```
db.sandbox.aggregate([
                      {$group: {_id: '$barcode',
                                count: {$sum: 1}
                               }
                      },
                      {$match: {count: {$gt:1} } }
                     ])
```

Comment: you can do aggregation for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) will help you to find duplicates. It is better than fetching records and do looping.

Comment: didn't even know what aggregation is. But worked perfect. Thx.